# Extjs 4 extending a form

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

Hi I'm trying to extend a form, I could extend the items using an auxiliar property like commonItems like this..

```
Ext.define('PC.view.FormEvento', {
        extend:'Ext.form.Panel',
        id:'FormEvento',
        url:'controller/action',
        bodyPadding:10,
        commonItems:[
            {
                xtype:'hiddenfield',
                name:'id',
                value:0
            },
]});
```

.. the I combine with the extened items's form like this

```
Ext.define('PC.view.FormEventoExtended', {
    extend:'PC.view.FormEvento',
    id:'FormEventoExtended',
    title:'Evento Extended',

    initComponent:function () {
        var me = this;

        Ext.applyIf(me, {
            items:me.commonItems.concat(
                [
                    {
                        xtype:'textfield',
                        fieldLabel:'personal1',
                        name:'personal1'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype:'textfield',
                        fieldLabel:'personal2',
                        name:'personal2'
                    }
                ])
        });
        me.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

where I concatenate the commonItems of base form to the personal items of the extened form. Is there a form to do it native in Ext 4 ?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know any native way of doing this, but I prefer a "best practice" of putting in a method *buildItems* in every class extending Component, which returns an array with items:

```
Ext.define('PC.view.FormEvento', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
    id: 'FormEvento',
    url: 'controller/action',
    bodyPadding: 10,

    initComponent: function () {
        this.items = buildItems();

        this.callParent(arguments);
    },

    buildItems: function () {
        return [
            {
                xtype: 'hiddenfield',
                name: 'id',
                value:0
            },
        ];
    }
]});
```

When you extend from this class, changing the items becomes a simple as overwriting the buildItems method, calling the parent and adding or inserting additional items:

```
Ext.define('PC.view.FormEventoExtended', {
    extend: 'PC.view.FormEvento',
    id: 'FormEventoExtended',
    title: 'Evento Extended',

    buildItems: function () {
        var items = this.callParent(arguments);

        return Ext.Array.push(items, [
            {
                xtype:'textfield',
                fieldLabel:'personal1',
                name:'personal1'
            },
            {
                xtype:'textfield',
                fieldLabel:'personal2',
                name:'personal2'
            }
        ]);
    }
});
```

When the number of items grows, it makes sense to create additional methods, e.g. *buildFieldsetAddressItems*. This comes with the benefit that your list of items stays more readable, imho.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply write something like this in `PC.view.FormEvento` constructor:

```
initComponent: function() {
   var me = this;

   me.items.push({
      xtype:'hiddenfield',
      name:'id',
      value:0
   });
   me.callParent(arguments);
}
```

by the time this constructor will get called, object will already have items configured in the child object.